# Category List changed into type and filter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dropdown

I am not sure if this is a woocommerce or a wordpress behaviour (I can't find anything about this). But it seems when the number of product categories become a lot, the backend admin dropdown changes into a type and filter box. I'd like to keep this as a dropdown menu. Is there any information, hook about this?

[image: Normal Situation]

[image: After unknown threshold number of categories]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a WooCommerce behaviour and can be modified with this filter
`woocommerce_product_category_filter_threshold` which defaults to 100.

You can use it like so

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_category_filter_threshold', 'return500');

function return500(){
    return 500;
}
```

The following also works for unlimited

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_category_filter_threshold', '__return_true');
```